# Grouping Data from Array into Subarrays

Tags: python, arrays, excel, grouping

I have a set of 100 rows of data from an excel sheet. The sheet is comprised of 4 columns [Date, Outbound Facility #, Destination Lat, Destination Lon].

I can index and group the dates together into a two arrays within the overall array (because data is recorded daily the dates are already clustered together), but my problem is because the Outbound Facility # are random I need a way to group the Destination (Lat,Lon) into an array for each Outbound Facility.

Ideally, I would like to be able to have an array where I could call `t[0][0]` and python returns all the Destination Lat/Lon on Day 1 for Outbound Facility 1.

```
file_location = "C:\Users\PythonPractice.xlsx"

OFs = 4
with xlrd.open_workbook(file_location) as workbook:
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

    Dates = (sheet.cell_value(i,0) for i in range(sheet.nrows))
    Day = [list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(Dates)]

d = []

for i in range(sheet.nrows):      
    DC = sheet.cell(i,1).value
    Lat = sheet.cell(i,2).value
    Lon = sheet.cell(i,3).value
    d.append([OF,Lat,Lon])

t = []
for i in range(2):
    T = [d[j:j+len(Day[i])] for j in range(0,len(Day),len(Day[i]))]         
    t.append(T)
```

Here is an excerpt from the excel file.

```
Date OF Lat Lon
1   1   1   100
1   2   2   99
1   3   3   98
1   4   4   97
1   1   5   96
1   2   6   95
1   3   7   94
1   4   8   93
1   1   9   92
1   2   10  91
1   3   11  90
1   4   12  89
2   3   51  50
2   4   52  49
2   1   53  48
2   2   54  47
2   3   55  46
2   4   56  45
2   1   57  44
2   2   58  43
2   3   59  42
2   4   60  41
2   1   61  40
```

So in this case Column 1-4 are [Date,OF,Lat,Lon]

I would really like to have every thing grouped by Date then Outbound Facility. I want it to look like this when I print t:

```
[[[[1,100],
   [5, 96],
   [9, 92]],
  [[2, 99],
   [6, 95],
   [10,91]],
  [[3, 98],
   [7, 94],
   [11,90]],
  [[4, 97],
   [8, 92],
   [12,89]]],
 [[[53,48],
   [57,44],
   [61,40]],
  [[54,47],
   [58,43]],
  [[51,50],
   [55,46],
   [59,42]],
  [[52,49],
   [56,45],
   [60,41]]]]
```

Comment: Can you post a handful of lines of the input file, and using that input data, post an example of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: use a 2-row input file to **debug** with printing `T, Day, Dates ...` out.

Comment: I went ahead and added the excel excerpt

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html)?  They have some nice ways of constructing dataframes that allow you to grab lots of data, filter it, visualize it, etc...

For your example (from what I can gather), you can do something like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('my_excel_file.xls')
```

Then when you want specific information

```
mask = (df['Date'] == some_date) & (df['Outbound Facility'] == some_outbound)
filtered_df = df[mask]
```

`filtered_df` will be a new dataframe only containing data that meets your criteria.  If you post an example file I can make sure this code is compatible but it should be pretty straight forward

Comment: Wow. pandas is an awesome module. I haven't run across it before. My only question is how do I put the values into an array to use them later for calculation? I understand that df[mask] shows all the matching values and their respective row numbers, but is there a way to store that data as above using pandas?

Comment: @JacCook i'm afraid I don't understand your question.  Do you mean store the information that comes from the `mask`?  If that's the case you the answer is yes, you can do tons with it.  `pandas` has functions built in to write dataframes to csv, excel, txt, etc.  You can also get the raw `numpy` array out of it.  I can answer more clearly if you elaborate on what you're confused about and what you want to do with the data

Comment: I edited the original post to include a more in depth synopsis of what I am looking for in the output of the code. I need to first group the data by the Dates. Then I need to group the data again into Outbound Facilities within the Dates. That way when I call t[0][0] it will display all the destination Lat/Lon's for the first day and first Outbound Facility.